# Output parameter is empty when calling Oracle package procedure using Oracle ADO in VBScript

Tags: oracle, vbscript, ado

I need to call Oracle package procedure from VBScript (from PowerDesigner app). It is 64-bit application so i am using Oracle 64-bit ODBC driver (Oracle client 12.1.0.2).

The job should be done with following code, which runs without any error but output values are empty:

```
Const ORAUser = "****"               
Const ORAPass = "****"     
Const ORASchema = "****"           
Const ORAInst = "****"                    
Const ORADRV  = "Oracle in OraClient12Home1"
Const ADO_CMD_STORED_PROC = 4

Dim Conn, ConnString, CmdStoredProc

Set Conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
ConnString = "Driver={" + ORADRV + "};Dbq=" + ORAInst + ";Uid=" + ORAUser + ";Pwd=" + ORAPass + ";"
Conn.Open ConnString

Set CmdStoredProc = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
With CmdStoredProc
  Set .ActiveConnection = Conn
  .CommandText = ORASchema & ".PDLOCKS_ADMIN.VBS_TEST"
  .CommandType = ADO_CMD_STORED_PROC
  .Parameters.Append CmdStoredProc.CreateParameter("i_input_num", 5, 1, 0, 1) 
  .Parameters.Append CmdStoredProc.CreateParameter("i_input_vchar", 200, 1, 4000, "1") 
  .Parameters.Append CmdStoredProc.CreateParameter("o_output_num", 5, 2, 0)
  .Parameters.Append CmdStoredProc.CreateParameter("o_output_vchar", 200, 2, 4000)
  .Execute
  Output .Parameters("o_output_num").Value ' EMPTY :-(
  Output .Parameters(2) ' EMPTY :-(
End With  

Conn.Close
Set Conn = Nothing
Set CmdStoredProc = Nothing
```

In Oracle database package procedure is everything processed correctly and input and output parameters are saved into table TEST:

```
PROCEDURE VBS_TEST (
  i_input_num    in  number
 ,i_input_vchar  in varchar2
 ,o_output_num   out number
 ,o_output_vchar out varchar2
)
IS
BEGIN
  insert into test values (to_char(i_input_num) || i_input_vchar);
  o_output_num := i_input_num + 1;
  o_output_vchar := i_input_vchar || '1';
  insert into test values (to_char(o_output_num) || o_output_vchar);
  commit;
END;
```

Comment: You're using the wrong data types and sizes for parameters, see [this helpful guide](http://www.carlprothman.net/Technology/DataTypeMapping/tabid/97/Default.aspx) that has never steered me wrong. Also, have you tested running the procedure from Oracle directly to see if the output variables are populated?

Comment: You should use constant in your code, it makes the code easier to read, see http://support.webecs.com/kb/a237/where-can-i-find-ado-constants-for-vbscript.aspx

Comment: Are you sure? Try `Output "Result: " & .Parameters("o_output_num").Value` In general I don't see any problem in your code.

Comment: @Lankymart What exactly is wrong in datatypes? These are even grabbed from ADO itself using `.Parameters.Refresh`, which should copy type definition from source. Running procedure in Oracle works fine.

Comment: @morto if they work, that's fine was just going off what that article recommends but I don't work in Oracle environments so I'm no authority on the subject. However you should specify the correct sizes, why pass a size of 0? In references to the datatypes, you pass 5 which is `adDouble` but you have the parameter in the procedure defined as `number` which is 131 which is `adNumeric` and should have a size of 9.